# How to optimise memory allocation in Python with large numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, h5py

I'm using numpy(1.15.4) and h5py(2.9.0) in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import sys

Ns, N, L, Nz = (40, 80, 3240, 160)
largeArray = np.zeros((Ns,N, L, Nz), dtype=complex)

for ids in range(Ns):
    for n in range(N):
        for l in range(L):
            #calling a bunch of numerical operations with pybind11 
            #and storing the results into a largeArray
            largeArray[ids, n, l]=ids+n+l*1j

f = h5py.File('myFile.hdf5', 'w')
f.create_dataset('largeArray', data=largeArray)
print('content:', largeArray.nbytes)
print('size:', sys.getsizeof(largeArray))
```

A large chunk of data has to be allocated 26.5GB, and the system reports 148 GB of memory usage. I assume the memory manager is swapping data in memory with the hard drive, right?. I'm using `pybind11` to wrap numerical operations, and I started breaking up the data into chunks in the outermost loop(`ids`) to store the data with `mpi` and `h5py` in [parallel](https://gist.github.com/apdavison/36126ee26067592ee69bf51b57fd3f31), but at some point I run out of storage. Any idea what can be eating up all the memory?

Comment: You could create the dataset with dtype and shape, but not data, and then generate and write chunks to the largerArray.

Comment: It won't help with memory, but `np.arange(Ns)[:,None,None]+np.arange(N)[None,:,None]+np.arange(L)[None,None,:]*1j` generates a (Ns,N,L) array that matches your `largeArray[:,:,:,0]`.